Blazor server app with cloudflare enabled does not load, too many redirects
This is a duplicate of this post
But I can't comment because I'm new here.
So I ask, how can I solve it today? Cloudflare has changed a lot and the only "fix" is just disabling the proxied cloudflare.
How to actually fix this today? It's a blazor server app with .NET 8 deployed in Linux with nginx
So... anybody knows?
When I try to access the domain, it returns an error with "too many redirects" but when I disable cloudflare's proxy, it loads the website and the websocket is opened properly.

The duplicate post you linked specifically says to create a page rule to disable HTML minification. That feature of Cloudflare has not changed. Have you tried creating a page rule like mentioned in that post?

@MarkB I tried but there's no such option now. If you try to disable minification it warns you it is deprecated and nothing happens even if you apply that rule. That's why I asked  here.

Problem solved https://community.cloudflare.com/t/blazor-server-side-app-not-working-when-cloudflare-is-enabled/670117
